# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack with string formatting

Tags: python, django

I am creating the html for an email using a Python string, like so:

```
      # Code setting up the message html
      message = "long html message string"

      scoped = ""
      if settings.DEBUG:
          scoped = "scoped"

      header = """                                                                
          <style %s type='text/css'>                                              
              @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){                          
                  .emailImage{                                                    
                      height:auto !important;                                     
                      max-width:200px !important;                                 
                      width: 100% !important;                                     
                  }                                                               
              }                                                                   
          </style>                                                                
          """ % scoped
      footer = "html message footer"

      message = header + message + footer

      # Code sending the message.
```

The problem is, the above code gives me the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. However, if I remove the `scoped` variable from the message, the html runs, i.e., this works (albeit without adding the scoped variable into my HTML as I want it to).

```
      # Code setting up the message html
      message = "long html message string"

      header = """                                                                
          <style type='text/css'>                                              
              @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){                          
                  .emailImage{                                                    
                      height:auto !important;                                     
                      max-width:200px !important;                                 
                      width: 100% !important;                                     
                  }                                                               
              }                                                                   
          </style>                                                                
          """
      footer = "html message footer"

      message = header + message + footer

      # Code sending the message.
```

Why is the first version throwing that error, and how can I address the ValueError?

Comment: Why are you building up HTML by string substitution? That is what templates are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an unescaped % symbol after the `width` element, add another % to escape it:

```
  header = """                                                                
      <style %s type='text/css'>                                              
          @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){                          
              .emailImage{                                                    
                  height:auto !important;                                     
                  max-width:200px !important;                                 
                  width: 100%% !important;                                     
              }                                                               
          }                                                                   
      </style>                                                                
      """ % scoped
```

Note that when you got rid of the `% scoped`, you were no longer formatting the string and the % character was no longer special.

Comment: Yes! I had earlier tried to escape it with `\%` and that didn't work - you have to escape using another `%` in this context?

Comment: Yea, in the old style formatting it is very similar to C `printf` where you also escape `%` with another `%`